# Why must uuid.h be "installed" on linux systems to be able to build many C++ programs rather than just put in include or lib folders

Tags: c++, include, uuid

All over the web, the answer to the question "uuid.h not found" is "install some kind of rpm or deb file". This may be appropriate for attempting to build some kind of open source project, which has dependencies on other open source, but it does not seem correct for building one's own software.

At my company, most of our own code can be built by getting the code from our source control and building it. Dependent headers, libs, etc. are included in the sync. However, whenever someone gets a uuid.h not found, soemone always says "do apt-get install uuid-dev" or something like that.

My question: what is so different about uuid.h that it must be installed like this? Our code uses ODBC too, but we don't need to "install" odbc headers. Ditto xml parsers, and many other third party code.

Comment: Are you sure dependent libs are included in version control?  Not only are libs usually ignored (purposely), but it doesn't make a ton of sense due to differing install bases, architectures, hardware configurations, etc.

Comment: @jedwards - actually it can make a lot of sense to put third party libs in your RCS.  Not for the reasons Marc is talking about, but because you want to be able to recreate any past build exactly as it was.  The easiest way to make this possible is to have the libraries it depends on checked in and tagged/branched/whatever along with your release.  You can go even further and include OS files for auto-deployment...something I know much less about.

Comment: @CrazyEddie, that does sound like a reasonable way to accomplish that

Comment: CrazyEddie describes my scenario well. While in the open source community, the source code is often the "product", in many companies the "product" is a fully built system targeted at a specific platform, ready to deploy.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there's anything magical about uuid.h that requires a packages installation; just that installing the package is a simpler step than adding the required files one by one, and it will be easier for you to keep them up to date through your Linux distro's package update utilities.

So installing the package is the simplest way to get a user going, and will keep them up to date without manual intervention.  I suspect there is a way to build from source and add the files one-by-one, but that is not as simple.

Comment: I think you are describing a situation in which someone is downloading and trying to build someone else's code, rather than people inside a company trying to build their own code (or get a build machine to build it). Installing a package is a simple way to get a single user working but doesn't solve the underlying problem: the code doesn't build without having to tweak machines first. That is a pain each time someone in the company wants to build something for the first time.